# wacom pen & touch cth-460 on debian

Tags: compiling, kernel-modules, tablet

Following instructions at http://lik.noblogs.org/post/2010/05/07/wacom-debian/

Though, i downloaded and built linuxwacom-0.8.8-11

```
./configure --enable-wacom --with-kernel=/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-5-686
```

completes without any problem, then copy

```
sudo cp src/2.6.30/wacom.ko /lib/modules/2.6.32-5-686/kernel/drivers/input/tablet/wacom.ko
```

unplug and replug,

```
jcress@debian:~/Downloads/linuxwacom-0.8.8-11$ dmesg | grep wacom
[  878.879686] usbcore: registered new interface driver wacom
[  878.879694] wacom: v1.52:USB Wacom tablet driver
[  963.774142] usbcore: deregistering interface driver wacom
[ 1613.534147] usbcore: registered new interface driver wacom
[ 1613.534671] wacom: v1.52-pc-0.4:USB Wacom tablet driver
```

and dmesg | grep input doesn't list the wacom

advice? Does this mean the module isn't working?

EDIT: === fixed === 
I did dist-upgrade to testing and it 'just works'

Comment: you did load the module, didnt you?

Comment: yeah.  a couple of times, rmmod insmod, depmod -a, et cetera

Comment: great to hear it works now :)  ...does it work including touch and buttons?

Comment: almost?  The touch is really odd, for some reason it's always right clicking, whether I want it to or not.. If you try to use it as a trackpad and 'pick up' your finger the cursor jumps.  It's a poor substitute for a mouse without the pen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'm posting this as an answer, seeing as the OP has resolved his/her issue*

Apparently, performing a `dist-upgrade` will fix this issue. Although without more information we cannot really say how.